# how to display property/key name in HandleBars.net

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, handlebars.js, handlebars.net

Hi this code works perfectly fine for Handlebar.js. What should I do to display key/property through c#/HandleBars.net ?

```
 {{#each myObject}}
    {{#if this.length}}
    <b>{{@key}}</b>
    {{#each this}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    <br>
    {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Update 5/14/16

Version **1.6.6** of Handlebars.Net includes 2 changes:

- Member resolution is case-insensitive (many devs were surprised that `{{length}}` and `{{Length}}` could not resolve to the same thing)

  - (In cases where there is an ambiguous match - i.e. `Length` and `length` are both present on the object, the binder will prefer the exact match)
- `this` can now be used in member paths, e.g. `this.length`

#### Original answer

We have had a few issues bubble up in the past few days that involve **case sensitivity** and member resolution. You are right this template should work as you have it; we're working on fixing that.

In the meantime, if you change `{{#if this.length}}` to `{{#if Length}}` it will work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
var htmlTemplateStr = //Open a resource or file containing your HTML template,
                      // and load it into this string

var LoadedTemplate = Handlebars.Compile(htmlTemplateStr);

var contextJson = //create a JSON object that will hold all the variables your 
                  // template will be looking for

var outputHtml = LoadedTemplate(contextJson);
```

**EDIT**

Your Key array will be a JSON array member of your JSON object. To display it, you'll need to add a HandleBars each block into your html template. It'll look something like this:

```
{{#each Key}}
    <!-- HTML to display whatever is in each object in the Key array -->
{{/each}}
```